# Can't get AngularJS animations to work on change of view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-animation

I have read the AngularJS docs, done several tutorials including the scotch and moo ones. I can get their sample code to run.

However, I don't seem to understand what is the trigger for Angular to apply the CSS styles to create the animations. I understand that angular 1.2 SHOULD apply them automatically but that does not seem to be working for me.

My goal is for the change of views (and therefore controllers) to be animated.
I am not showing the content for the sub-views or the other CSS, but I can if need be.

Below is the code:

Here is the JS

```
var triStartApp = angular.module('triStartApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute']);
// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
// configure our routes
routeFunction = function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'html/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    });

    // route for the about page
    $routeProvider.when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'html/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutController'
    });    
};

triStartApp.config(routeFunction);

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
triStartApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

triStartApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.view.ng-enter {
  animation:view_enter 1s;
}

@keyframes view_enter {
  0% { left:100%; }
  30% { left:80%; }
  100% { left:0; }
}

.view.ng-leave {
  animation:view_leave 1s;
}
@keyframes view_leave {
  0% { left:0; }
  30% { left:-50px; }
  100% { left:-100%; }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="triStartApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.ico"> -->

        <title>TriStart</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom styles for "cover" template -->
        <link href="/css/cover.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/animations.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom styles for tristart  -->
        <link href="/css/tristart.css" rel="stylesheet">    

    </head>

    <body ng-controller="mainController">          

        <div class="site-wrapper">

            <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

                <div class="cover-container">

                    <div class="masthead clearfix">

                        <div class="inner">
                            <h2 class="masthead-brand">TriStart</h2>
                            <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="tristart-lead">(triangle startup resources)</p>                       
                            </div>                        
                        </div>                        
                    </div>


                    <div id="main" >
                        {{ message }}  
                        <!-- angular templating -->
                        <!-- angular templating -->
                        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
                        <div>
                            <div class="view" ng-view></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/script.js"></script>             
        <script src="/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/lib/docs.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing complex, custom animation, you might be able to consider using [ng-fx](https://github.com/Hendrixer/ng-Fx).